# Setting up TypeScript for Firefox (so it knows about types like browser.storage)

Tags: typescript, firefox

According to Mozilla docs I should be able to use `browser.storage.sync.get` for my extension, but I'm having some difficulty making typescript understand that I can use `browser`.

I have tried this (which works for using `chrome`)

> package

```
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.209",
    "@types/firefox": "^0.0.31",
```

> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": ["chrome", "firefox"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "scripts", "bundle.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "scripts"]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global `browser` variable is part of the webextension environment, typescript bindings are provided in [@types/firefox-webext-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/firefox-webext-browser):

```
npm i -D @types/firefox-webext-browser
```

You can make it available without having to import by registering it in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "firefox-webext-browser"
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I also came across `@wdio/globals/types` (much smaller size) - any thoughts on that?

Comment: Oh, `@wdio/globals/types` are bindings for WebdriverIO, a testing framework. Looks like their [browser object](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/) supplies information about the environment the tests are run in. It is not what `browser` looks like inside a web extension